# How to get a single element from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a single element from a collection stored in Firebase.

I have the collection name and the key element.

my getting method is like so:

```
  get(collectionName: string, key) {
    return this.db.collection(collectionName).doc(key).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

But I am unable to show the data.

I have already tried this one:

```
  getCollectionItem(collectionName: string, key) {

    return this.db.collection(collectionName).doc(key).valueChanges().
    subscribe(objectItem => {
      console.log(objectItem);
      return objectItem;
    });

  }
```

Console log shows it correctly. objectItem has the value that I want!

```
{desc: "Testing description", name: "Testing name", nameToSearch: "testing name", price: 20000}
desc: "Testing description"
name: "Testing name"
nameToSearch: "testing name"
price: 20000
```

I need to get these values outside this method to show in a modal but `getCollectionItem` method always returns an object and I do not know how to get what is displayed on the console.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get information from the text you receive from Firestore by using a String process algorithm ? or ? (I still don't get your mean)

Comment: not exactly, but TheUnreal post clarified where the issue was. have a look! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Angular as well as Typescript, it's always useful to use types to understand issues like this one:

```
return this.db.collection(collectionName).doc(key).valueChanges().
    subscribe(objectItem => {
      console.log(objectItem);
      return objectItem;
    });
```

Assuming this code is in your service, the issue here is that you are returning a `Subscription`, and you also want to neglect `return objectItem;` and just return an observable.

In your component, you should subscribe to this observable and wait for the data to arrive. Check this out:

Service:

```
  getCollectionItem(collectionName: string, key): Observable<any> {

    return this.db.collection(collectionName).doc(key).valueChanges();

  }
```

Component (where you want to get and use the data):

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.myService.getCollectionItem('myItem', 'myKey').subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.data = data;
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It solved my problem! one more question: is there any way to subscribe to this observable inside the service and in the component just accessing the array?

Comment: Yes, I'm not advising, but you can subscribe and save the data in the service, then you can use it anywhere the service is injected. It may also lead to a memory leak if you are not unsubscribing from the observable (where in the solution I provided you can unsubscribe when the component unmounts)